# How to change imakeidx section title without breaking the .ind file creation?

Tags: indexing, counters, imakeidx

I'm using a macro that messed around with the `\section` command, breaking `\printindex` in the process when using `imakeidx`. I'm pretty sure the problem lies about lines 252-253 in `imakeidx.sty`:

```
\def\imki@indexlevel{%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}{\section}{\chapter}*}
```

For some reason I can get either `\makeindex` or `\printindex` (Correct section title, uncompilable `\jobname.ind`), but not both, to work. Where is it going wrong?

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pageanchor]{hyperref}

\newrobustcmd{\PreviousSectionTitle}{}%
\newrobustcmd{\CurrentSectionTitle}{}%
\newcounter{PreviousSectionCounter}%
\setcounter{PreviousSectionCounter}{0}%    
\newcounter{NextSectionCounter}%
\setcounter{NextSectionCounter}{0}        
\newcounter{CurrentSectionCounter}%
\setcounter{CurrentSectionCounter}{0}    
\newcounter{LastSectionValue}
\newcounter{FirstSectionValue}

\fancypagestyle{FootLinks}{
\lfoot{
    \ifnumequal%
    {\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{\number\value{FirstSectionValue}}{}
    {
                    {\GeneratePreviousSectionHyperlink{CurrentSectionCounter}{PreviousSectionCounter}{1} }
    }%
}% 
\rfoot{
    \ifnumequal%
    {\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{\number\value{FirstSectionValue}}%
        {\GenerateNextSectionHyperlink{CurrentSectionCounter}{NextSectionCounter}{LastSectionValue}}% 
    {\ifnumequal%
                    {\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{\number\value{LastSectionValue}} {  }%
                    { \GenerateNextSectionHyperlink{CurrentSectionCounter}{NextSectionCounter}{LastSectionValue} }%
    }%
}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\GenerateNextSectionHyperlink}[3]{\ifnumequal{\number\value{#1}}{\number\value{#3}}{}{\hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{#2}}{\nameref*{CurrentSection::\number\value{#2}::Title}~\(\rightarrow\)}}}    
\newrobustcmd{\GeneratePreviousSectionHyperlink}[3]{\ifnumequal{\number\value{#1}}{1}{}{\hyperlink{CurrentSection::\number\value{#2}}{\(\leftarrow\)~\nameref*{CurrentSection::\number\value{#2}::Title}}}}

\makeindex%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}   
\let\LaTeXStandardSection\section%
\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{%
\stepcounter{CurrentSectionCounter}%
\ifnumequal{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{1}{%
\setcounter{PreviousSectionCounter}{1}%
\expandafter\renewrobustcmd{\CurrentSectionTitle}{%
#2}%
}{%
\makeatletter
\edef\@@oldtitle{\CurrentSectionTitle}
\expandafter\renewrobustcmd{\PreviousSectionTitle}{%
\@@oldtitle
}%
\expandafter\renewrobustcmd{\CurrentSectionTitle}{%
#2%
}%
\setcounter{PreviousSectionCounter}{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}
\addtocounter{PreviousSectionCounter}{-1}
}%
\phantomsection
\hypertarget{CurrentSection::\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{}%
\immediate\write1{%
\string\phantomsection%
\string\newlabel{CurrentSection::\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}::Title}{{\thesection}{\thepage}{#2}}%
}%
\makeatother
\setcounter{NextSectionCounter}{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}
\ifnumequal{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{\number\value{LastSectionValue}}{}{%
\addtocounter{NextSectionCounter}{1}
}%
\phantomsection
\LaTeXStandardSection[#2]{#2}%
}%

\pagestyle{FootLinks}
\newpage
\section{dummy1}
\index{text}{teeeeeeeeeeeeeeext}
\newpage
\section{dummy2}
\printindex%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\section{dummy4}
\newpage
\section{dummy5}
\newpage
\section{dummy6}
\newpage
\section{dummy7}
\end{document}
```